# EXC_BAD_ACCESS and MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, mpmusicplayercontroller

I wrote an app that I haven't worked on in awhile.  It started in Xcode 7.3.1, but worked fine in Xcode 8.3.3.  I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to run it on an iPhone 8 with iOS 11.4.1 (I wish I never updated the iOS, but now I'm stuck).  But the app still runs fine on my old iPhone 5 with iOS 10.3.3.

My Mac runs Sierra and has Xcode 8.3.3 and 9.2.  I did copy the appropriate support files into the correct folder in each Xcode app (something I learned on this site).  That trick had worked for awhile!

I decide to build a little "Hello World" app under Xcode 9.2 just to simplify things.  If I remove the MPMusicPlayerController() below, the app installs and runs fine.  But, with that code, it crashes on self.myMPMusicPlayerController.playbackState == .stopped.

Can anyone suggest anything?  Thank you very much ahead of time.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var nowPlaying: UIButton!

var myMPMusicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // The following is a tiny bit of an app
    // My mac is running Sierra so it can only take Xcode 8.3.3 or 9.2
    // I will be updating my mac at least to High Sierra soon, so it will be able to take Xcode 9.4.1
    // I have copied in the appropriate support file folders accordingly. So I have the 11.4 (15F79) folder in place

    // The following line, worked fine using Xcode 8.3.3 and an iPhone8 running 11.2 and an iPhone5 running 10.3.3
    // The following line, crashes on an iPhone8 running 11.4.1 but RUNS FINE on the iPhone5 running 10.3.3

    // I'm getting the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70)
    if self.myMPMusicPlayerController.playbackState == .stopped {

        // Hide the nowPlaying button.
        nowPlaying.isHidden = true
    } else {

        // Show the nowPlaying button.
        nowPlaying.isHidden = false
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// I added this just for a simple test
@IBAction func nowPlayingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.myLabel.text = "Hello"
}

}
```

Comment: Have your tried enabling Zombies to determine which deallocated object your application is still accessing? Can you provide the log for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: I haven't tried Zombies.  I will try that!  Also, I'll track down the log.  The thing is, the code above IS the entire application.  I deleted the app from the iPhone8 and Xcode installed this little app.  No luck, crash.  So far the only "common denominator" is the installation of iOS 11.4.1.

Comment: I enabled Zomies turned on Logging -> Malloc Stack.  What was dumped out into the console is: Hello(1654,0x1b6fdbb40) malloc: stack logs being written into /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F37A5D0-2F42-4B0E-802C-BB5B57CFA84C/tmp/stack-logs.1654.103364000.Hello.33AvRC.index
Hello(1654,0x1b6fdbb40) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
(lldb)

Comment: Maybe the 11.4 (15F79) doesn't cut it with iOS 11.4.1.  I can't find 11.4.1 (15G77) anywhere.  I may just have to install High Sierra and then Xcode 9.4.1 (I'm assuming that that would give me the 11.4.1 (15G77) support folder).  Other than that, this is crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code, unfortunately I am on Xcode 10.1 but I am having a compile error in the initialization of `MPMusicPlayerController` and shows the following error: 
[image]

From [Apple's Documentation of the MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller) class you may try initializing with
`MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer` or `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer` depending on your use case. I have tried this and ran on 11.4.1 and didn't run into any crashes.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you for the help (sorry for the delay).  I did track down the support files: 11.4.1 (15G77).  I put the folder in the right place in Xcode 8.3.3, but it didn't work.  I didn't rename the folder to simply 11.4.1.  Not sure if that matters.  Anyway, my old code worked for a long time.  Using MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer solved it in the mini app (above) and the big multi-view controller app.  Thank you very much for helping me out.  I have more to learn!